# Removing raid metadata from drives

Tags: linux, raid, hardware, mdadm, dmraid

Normally when I have a drive which contains raid metadata e.g. from fakeraid or a hardware raid card I can get rid of it with:

```
dmraid -r -E /dev/sdX
```

Or if that doesnt work, doing a simple `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX` normally works

But I have four WD RE4 drives here and neither option seems to work. `dmraid` just gives me a CRC error when it reads the drive. I know the drives are fine and they've been checked with `smart` + WD diagnostics anyway

The actual error on `dmraid` is:

```
ddf1: physical drives with CRC 5CD0C0DB, expected FFFFFFFF on /dev/sda
ERROR: ddf1: Cannot find physical drive description on /dev/sda!
ERROR ddf1: setting up RAID device /dev/sad
nor aid disks and with names: "/dev/sda"
```

Gives the same CRC error for all disks so clearly something strange the raid controller did

I've even formatted them with mdadm through rescuemode to see if that would overwrite it but no difference.

Comment: And what happens if you do `dd ... count=2`?

Answer (score 8):

same problem here today.

Solved using the following:

You need your wrong mapper like => `/dev/mapper/ddf1XXXXXXXX`

Get it using :

```
fdisk -l
```

Then (this is just to be sure)

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/mapper/ddf1xxxxxxxxxxxxx bs=512 count=200000
```

Finally clean it up:

```
 dmsetup remove /dev/mapper/ddf1xxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

And check it that it just disappeared from `fdisk -l`

Comment: Thank you so much! I was this was documented in more places

Answer (score 8):

In this case wipefs utility should work.
`wipefs -a /dev/sdb` for example - delete all magic strings (metadata).
But afaik there is some hardware raids, that `wipefs` doesn't know about.

Comment: Very simple. This worked for `ddf_raid_member` and `linux_raid_member`.

Comment: Also, without the `-a` option, it shows what it found: " When used without any options, wipefs lists all visible filesystems and the offsets of their basic signatures".